# Android Toast inside child fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter, android-toast

My current setup includes a mainActivity with FragmentPagerAdapter, with different tabs. One of the tabs consist of different child fragments from bottom navigation bar.

Now, all the fragments, including the child fragments have a menu item button on the top corner, and when pressed it triggers a toast each time.

The problem I am having is that when I am in any of the tabs and press the menu button, it triggers the toast from the child fragment. Is there a way to make the toast of the child fragment (i.e fragment 3 from the pic) to only trigger when tab 2 is selected.

I've attached a picture to better illustrate this. Thanks.

[image]

The code pattern I've been using for the toast part is:

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

```
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.menu_item_change_view) {
        if(Mode == 0){
            Mode = 1;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(Mode == 1){
            Mode = 2;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Mode = 0;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Your Activity should probably provide a method to say which tab is selected, then you could access that through `getActivity()`

Comment: @cricket_007 yep you're right. I just had to use the method in Fragment 2 and do checks for which child fragments were visible to the user. Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Sorry I couldn't really provide an official answer, it wasn't too clear what data you had available to work with